# Should url be stored in encoded or decoded form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, url, encoding

My question is a bit weird, but let me explain:

1. Assuming valid URI doesn't allow unicode per RFC-2396, all unicode in URI should be escaped using percentage encoding.
2. A valid URL should be a valid URI, so we should use `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` instead of `http://example.com/你好` when making request or putting them in `href` (even though most browsers can handle the latter case).
3. More over, we accept user-submitted URLs, which are encoded as well (since browsers encode them when you copy URL from address bar).
4. So we made a decision (likely a mistake) to store them as `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD`, instead of `http://example.com/你好`, after-all, that's the original input and the correct url.

My question comes when I try to display such URLs, given they are user-submitted, I need to run xss filter on these data. Some implementations, such as [xss-filters](https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters) appear to run [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) as part of the filter, meaning `%` will be double-encoded, eg. `%E4` -> `%25E4`, breaking url in the process.

So should we have stored url in decoded form (even though they are invalid)? It doesn't make much sense to me to run `decodeURI` on output...

Comment: "It doesn't make much sense to me to run decodeURI on output" --- it does make a lot of sense: the data stored must be in the generic form, and then you derive from it as per the requirements. For rendering on the page you *may* (not *have*) decode it back, for using it for something else you might use its canonical form. The same is applicable for virtually any type of data.

Comment: @zerkms so you are supporting storing `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD`?

Comment: I'm supporting storing any data in its canonical and valid form, so yes.

Comment: @zerkms cheers, I guess I should also talk to `xss-filters` author about this.

Comment: opened a github issue in case ppl are interested: https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

First, RFC 2396 is obsoleted by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Second, **yes**, you should have stored your URIs in decoded form if your storage mechanism allows it.

**Update**
From [Section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4)

> Under normal circumstances, the only time when octets within a URI
> are percent-encoded is during the process of producing the URI from
> its component parts.

**Update 2**
Furthermore, a string of unicode characters representing a URI is, in fact, an IRI. See [RFC 3987](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3987.txt)

Comment: but it's also an invalid url, so we have to encode it in almost all use-case. see comment to my main post for conflicting suggestion...

Comment: Could you please put some thoughts of why you think so? Not going to say your point is wrong, just keen to see what stands behind it.

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald from the same paragraph "Once produced, a URI is always
   in its percent-encoded form."

Comment: Practically, a string with unicode characters meant to represent a URI is an IRI, defined in [RFC 3987](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-3987.html)

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald that is really interesting. But it does not convince us that URIs should be stored decoded.

Comment: "Furthermore, a string of unicode characters representing a URI is, in fact, an IRI" --- that's simply not true. URI may represent any unicode character using percent notation.

Comment: How you store data is a detail. The matter is the use of the stored data.

Comment: "How you store data is a detail" --- that's the subject of the question.

Comment: It says "string of unicode characters"; not percent-encoded characters. I know what the subject is, and that is what my answer addresses.

Comment: Upvoted for being pedantic and correct in general. What I cannot agree though is that the software around us is implemented to deal with URIs, hence relying on IRIs is dangerous, hence it can be misinterpreted.

Comment: Your usage of data is subject to context. Your storage of data is subject to ease of use, among other practicalities. In the end, data is stored as binaries on some form of medium; your software, i.e., browser, doesn’t understand that either.

Comment: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls is what defines URLs. It supersedes those RFCs.

Comment: @MathiasBynens See my comment to your answer on why this is not correct.

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#goals. If you prefer to stick to ancient RFCs that don’t match reality then be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

Note that https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls is what defines URLs. It supersedes those RFCs you mentioned.

I.e., your premise is incorrect, specifically this section:

> A valid URL should be a valid URI, so we should use `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` instead of `http://example.com/你好` when making request or putting them in href (even though most browsers can handle the latter case).

What makes you say that? `http://example.com/你好` is a perfectly valid URL.

Comment: ok thx for making that clear, so URL spec is a moving target. but still, user put in `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` by default, due to browser taking care of the encoding when copying. So I would at least guess that's the preferred version.

Comment: or maybe you mean `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` and `http://example.com/你好` are not the same url? but either way, I still want to know if ppl should ever store url in decoded form.

Comment: They resolve to the same resource, but `http://example.com/你好` is what I would store.

Comment: Hmm, I think only browser can resolve `http://example.com/你好` to `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` automagically? And in my chrome dev tool it always show up as `http://example.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD`. I tried doing this on node.js with `http` module and my own `node-fetch` module, no luck.

Comment: WHATWG’s specs doesn’t supersede IETF’s specs in any way. They are two different bodies publishing specifications; non of which supersede each other. WHATWG _only_ addresses the URL; IETF addresses the super class URI. WHATWG _only_ addresses URLs in respect to the Web.

Comment: @Frederik WHATWG URLs encompass URIs. The WHATWG URL Standard is the one reference you should use for anything. Read [its “goals” section](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#goals).

Comment: @MathiasBynens No, WHATWG is *not* the organization we should use for *anything*.  The W3C spec is a better guide to the stable features as implemented already in browsers. For example, it has dropped the `<hgroup>` element, warns about the lack of implementations of the outlining algorithm and has much better advice on using the `<main>` element today to make websites more accessible to people with disabilities. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/W3C-WHATWG-Differences

Comment: @Frederik Why are you suddenly talking about HTML specs?

Comment: @MathiasBynens You advised to use WHATWG specs for *anything*. And these were merely examples as to why WHATWG is *not* a good reference.